# Saving and serving images in a Java Web app

Tags: java, image, jsp, web, servlets

I'm making an ecommerce app for school, the app has a product page that displays a jpg image for each product. The /img folder is inside my project folder (see code for path) and the link in html is just `./img/ + img name`.
The images and products are dynamically added through a form in the admin panel that gives the image and other data as multipart/form-data to my servlet.
This is the code that saves the image in the aforementioned folder

```
                Part filePart = request.getPart("slika");
                String fileName = Paths.get(filePart.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString();
                                           // Ugly absolute path
                File filePath = new File("C:\\Users\\dgudo\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Faks\\Sesti semestar\\Internet Programerski alati\\Projekat\\CateringService\\web\\img");
                File file = new File(filePath, fileName);                

                try ( InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream()) {
                    
                    Files.copy(fileContent, file.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                } catch (IOException ie) {
                    request.setAttribute("msg", ie.getMessage());
                }
```

This works, but i'm using that ugly absolute path that's unique to my local machine.
Using a relative path doesn't work, it tells me the required resource couldn't be found, and using `System.getProperty("user.dir")` returns the path of the Tomcat server running the web app, where it obviously doesn't find anything.

So i've got a few questions:

1. Without internet access (environment I'll be presenting the app in at uni) what's the best way of saving and serving the jpg's,

   1.1 Should I leave it as is and hope the professor doesn't see the path (there's 2000+ lines of code in the project, easy to miss)?

   1.2 Should I move my /img folder to the path given by `System.getProperty("user.dir")` and serve/save there. If yes, how can I set the result of `System.getProperty("user.dir")` as a global variable somewhere so I can use it inside JSP code?
2. In an actual production environment where are images saved and served from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1:

1.1 : is a good approach, it should only be revised

1.2 : if you like to user home directory you should use System.getProperty("user.home") instead of System.getProperty("user.dir")

Normally, while the launch of the application you should create a temporary folder myapplicationimp" on user.home directory in which you manage the images.

EX : you can use @PostConstruct if you use springframework that check and create the folder instantly after bean creation (still an example).

Question 2:

In production save data we use the same aproache that you used, or a third-party environnement to like distant repositories (as google drive) or databases.

hope this will help